Google Sheets API not working when API restriction is set
I wrote a little Android App in Android Studio (Kotlin) that basically filters and sorts data.
The app receives the data from a Google Sheet that is connected via API.
Everything works fine, until I set an application restriction for Android Apps. Package Name and SHA-1 certificate fingerprint (debug key) are correct. I checked them like...often. As soon as it's set, Database is not accessable - without any fail.
It's tested via emulator and physical device. Via Logcat I only receive an 403 error for the API request, without further description.
As I am a total noob in programming, please let me know, if I should provide further info.
Thanks a lot.
